# Как правильно подсчитать на сколько процентов число больше другого чиста

Tags: javascript

Как правильно подсчитать на сколько процентов `sum2` больше `sum`

Но `sum2` может быть меньше `sum`, поэтому нужно вывести минусовой процент

Нужна какая то отдельная функция которая будет принимать два числа

```js
let sum = 213.312;
let sum2 = 321.77565;
```

И чтобы не было такого типа `15,99999999999999999999%`
Нужно максимально качественно реализовать такую функцию

Comment: Math.round(100*(sum2-sum)/sum)/100

Comment: @br3t данный код у меня выводит `0.51%`, на реальность совсем не похоже

Comment: а какова реальность?

Comment: @Squeli47 Уберите из формулы `/100`.

Comment: @br3t должно быть около 50% эта формула неверная `Math.round(100*(sum2-sum)/sum)/100`

Comment: Написал в долях, для перевода в проценты вам выше подсказали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function procent(sum2, sum, fix=2){
  if(sum === 0) return (100).toFixed(fix) +'%';
  return (100*(sum2-sum)/sum).toFixed(fix) +'%';
}

let sum = 213.312;
let sum2 = 321.77565;
let result = procent(sum2, sum);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Если sum будет 0, то ответ должен быть '∞ %' или '- ∞ %'. А при sum2 равном нулю, ответ будет '0%'. Также в вашем текущем варианте возвращать можно сразу строку: `if(sum === 0) return '100%';`.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev согласен, можно доработать